# Google analytics Demographics map in asp.net

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net-mvc-4

Does it possible to integrate google analytics  demographics map in my asp.net mvc 4 web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I had a task to add map like Google Analytics' one to own website. And I made it using  [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/). It is pretty easy to integrate and use (though have a few minor issues and outdated samples). In case you need to display GA's data you can just fetch it using GA API and display on this map.